# How to create (SharePoint Hosted-App) image slider apps for SharePoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, office-365, sharepoint-hosted-app

i'm new in SharePoint Online
Currently trying to create (SharePoint Hosted-App) Image Slider App for SharePoint Online(office 365)
please Suggest Some Artical or Some Information How To create Image slider App in office 365(SharePoint Online)

Comment: You want to create it programmatically (using JQuery for example) or just want to add an app from store? there are some free image slider apps in https://store.office.com/

Comment: trying to use “Napa” Office 365 Development Tools, need to create new (custom) image slider app  ,      i have HTML for slider,i want to follow that html to create   image slider, (no use of Visual Studio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Napa, then its pretty straightforward.

- Create a new project using napa
- Do your logic in the Clientapppart.aspx so that users can add it to their pages[The step is necessary if you want your app to be allowed to add as app part to pages].
- Add the reference js and css files to the package

Answer (score 0):

First Create a New SharePoint Hosted app.
Add a new client web part.
Write your html structure for the Slider.

write the JavaScript code to retrieve the list which store the url for the images which you want to show if you want customizable slider.

Now add your app-part to page like you add web-part.